# PHP - Convert unicode string to HTML entities

Tags: php, unicode

I need to take a unicode string to HTML Entities.

Let's say the string is: ιи¢яє∂ιвℓє ѕкιℓℓѕ

I want it to convert it to `&iota;&#1080;&cent;&#1103;&#1108;&part;&iota;&#1074;&#8467;&#1108; &#1109;&#1082;&iota;&#8467;&#8467;&#1109;`

In order to be able to store it in my SQL db and then output the desired text later.

This basically has the functionality I want, where you type in a string and itn converts it: http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/unicode-html-entities-convertor.php

I'm not very familiar with UTF-8/ASNII/different types of special characters in general, But I'd like it to be able to handle all the Unicode characters here: https://unicode-table.com/en/

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I tried all combinations of uft8_decode, htmlentities, htmlspecialchars and mb_convert_encoding and I can't get the desired result.

Thank you for looking!

Comment: Why not use a UTF8 table?

Comment: You mean just set the collation to utf8_bin in phpmyadmin?

That worked actually, I thought if I put it to utf8 it would only accept those special characters and reject normal letters but it works for normal English characters too.  (As I said I've never dealt with special characters before)

If that's all I have do then thank you so much, that's amazing and a huge help.

Comment: Yes, standard characters are also in the utf8 character set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Thank you again I appreciate all the help and quick replies!

Comment: HTML encoding is not for database storage.

Comment: You should read up on the different encodings and collations before choosing utf8_bin, you'd get much better unicode support with a utf8mb4_unicode collation...